# Select rows with max date from table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have such [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKmUS.png) and need table 2 result. I am trying to select rows with max date grouped by project_id and ordered by id. And result table must have id column. Tried such request:

```
SELECT MAX(charges.id) as id, 
       "charges"."profile_id", MAX(failed_at) AS failed_at 
FROM "charges" 
GROUP BY "charges"."profile_id" 
ORDER BY "charges"."id" ASC
```

And have error:

> ERROR:  column "charges.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function)

Example table

| id | profile_id | failed_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01.01.2021 |
| 2 | 1 | 01.02.2021 |
| 3 | 1 | 01.03.2021 |
| 4 | 2 | 01.06.2021 |
| 5 | 2 | 01.05.2021 |
| 6 | 2 | 01.04.2021 |

Needed result

| id | profile_id | failed_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 01.03.2021 |
| 4 | 2 | 01.06.2021 |

Comment: Can some more information be provided, as per the error given, it shouldn't have come up as **max(charges.id)** has already been used which is an aggregate function.

Comment: The issue is the `ORDER BY "charges"."id"`. Not sure the result you are looking for but `ORDER BY max("charges"."id")` will at least get the query to complete. If that is not the output you want then provide example data showing the starting data and what you want outputted. Add as update to your question.

Comment: Thanks for comments, you can see table and output examples in  attached img.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKmUS.png

Comment: Do not post textual data as images, see here [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Copy and paste data as text to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT charges.*
FROM charges
INNER JOIN 
( 
    SELECT
        profile_id,
        MAX(charges.failed_at) AS MaxFailed_at
    FROM charges
    GROUP BY profile_id
) AS xQ ON charges.profile_id = xQ.profile_id AND charges.failed_at = xQ.MaxFailed_at
```